# Can't change span content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got this span:

```
<span id="inicial"></span>
```

and this javascript inside a button click:

```
    var pat = /\/\S+\//i;
    context = '';
    context = $('#cmd').attr('value');
    context= context.match(pat);
alert(context); //this gives correctly the string i need    
if (context.length){
    $('#inicial').text(context); //but it fails to change the text inside the span
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Also i noticed that it affects the whole click function, it just stops working. What could possibly be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `.match()` returns an *array*, not a string. But `.text(parm)` requires `parm` to be a *string*.

So after the `.match()`, you should do something like:

```
context = context[0];
```

or use some other methodology to convert at least the first element in the array to a string, if not the full array.

Here's the reference for `.match()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

And the ref for `.text(parm)`: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

try -- edited as per @Jonathan M
 answer

```
$('#inicial').html(context[0]);
```

Comment: In which case OP's `.text()` is valid, and you don't really need to instantiate a `new String` object.

Comment: @Russell Dias - its removed but i thought it might be object thats y its causing problme ans used new string for it....